# Are there any alternative approaches to ARIMAX that include external regressors?

Tags: time-series

I have been searching for time-series techniques that can model highly volatile data, but most techniques that are recommended like GARCH, BSTS, TBATS, etc. don't have a very clear-cut way to include external regressors. Are there any alternate popular techniques, especially non-linear or non-parametric ones that use external regressors?

Comment: Neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

BSTS has a way to include external regressors. I am actually using this model at the moment and the inclusion is pretty clear in R package bsts.

*bsts* "This function can be used either with or without contemporaneous predictor variables (in a time series regression)." 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/bsts.pdf

Example 7:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bsts/versions/0.9.2/topics/bsts

Answer (score 0):

You can always model your time series using any non-time-series model you like, including nonlinear or nonparametric regression, then model the time series of residuals using a standard (or other) time series method.

This is the approach taken in R's `forecast::auto.arima()`, [which runs a standard OLS regression with ARIMA errors](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).